# Laravel Backpack MyAccountController

Tags: php, laravel, crud, laravel-backpack

I am quite new to backpack and I'm trying to add a field to my Account settings page but can't seem to find the controller nor the view, any help is appreciated, thanks !

I tried looking into app/http/controllers but had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

According to their docs: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/base-about, you need to create a my_account.blade.php file:

> If you only want to add a few new inputs, you can do that by creating
> a file in **resources/views/vendor/backpack/base/my_account.blade.php**
> that uses code from the same file in the Backpack package, but adds
> the inputs you need. Remember to also make these fields $fillable in
> your User model.